# Force widget inside a container to limit itself to one row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am relatively new to Flutter and having a layout problem that I feel should be easy to do. I am trying to render a `MarkdownBody` (that contains some HTML text) as the title of a `ListTile`. If the title is too long it overflows. If I could use a `Text` widget instead of a `MarkdownBody` then the solution would be very easy: use `maxLines: 1` and `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis`. But since the title contains HTML I am using `MarkdownBody`, so that's how I am creating the title:

```
   return new Container(
      height: 25.0,
      child: new Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
            child: new MarkdownBody(
              data: converted,
              styleSheet: MarkdownStyleSheet(
                p: textStyle,
                strong: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

That's how it looks like:

[image]

Each row in that search result is a `ListTile` wrapped inside a `Container`, where its title and subtitle are created as shown above. What I am trying to do is to make sure that both title and subtitle are cut off if the text is too long. I tried wrapping the `MarkdownBody` inside various layout widgets; e.g. `Container`, `SizedBox`, `Row` with `Expanded`, but couldn't fix the overflow problem.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to clone the original package and add an extra widget in there so that you can provide `overflow`/`maxLines` properties and interrupt/extend the parsing logic when `overflow` and/or `maxLines` is set to limit the children that get built.

Working on the assumption that the length of the markdown is minimal for your incoming data, you could just extend `MarkdownWidget` in your own project instead and hack it in like this (saves you writing your own parser or having to clone another project):

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_markdown/flutter_markdown.dart';

class SingleLineMarkdownBody extends MarkdownWidget {
  final TextOverflow overflow;
  final int maxLines;

  const SingleLineMarkdownBody(
      {Key key,
      String data,
      MarkdownStyleSheet styleSheet,
      SyntaxHighlighter syntaxHighlighter,
      MarkdownTapLinkCallback onTapLink,
      Directory imageDirectory,
      this.overflow,
      this.maxLines})
      : super(
          key: key,
          data: data,
          styleSheet: styleSheet,
          syntaxHighlighter: syntaxHighlighter,
          onTapLink: onTapLink,
          imageDirectory: imageDirectory,
        );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, List<Widget> children) {
    var richText = _findWidgetOfType<RichText>(children.first);
    if (richText != null) {
      return RichText(
        text: richText.text,
        textAlign: richText.textAlign,
        textDirection: richText.textDirection,
        softWrap: richText.softWrap,
        overflow: this.overflow,
        textScaleFactor: richText.textScaleFactor,
        maxLines: this.maxLines,
        locale: richText.locale);
    }

    return children.first;
  }

  T _findWidgetOfType<T>(Widget widget) {
    if (widget is T) {
      return widget as T;
    }

    if (widget is MultiChildRenderObjectWidget) {
      MultiChildRenderObjectWidget multiChild = widget;
      for (var child in multiChild.children) {
        return _findWidgetOfType<T>(child);
      }
    } else if (widget is SingleChildRenderObjectWidget) {
      SingleChildRenderObjectWidget singleChild = widget;
      return _findWidgetOfType<T>(singleChild.child);
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, one remark: `RichText` doesn't have a `locale` field (at least in Flutter v0.5.1) - besides that your solution works fine in my case.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on v0.5.7 on the dev channel. Just ignore that field if you're not :p

Answer (score 1):

You will have to modify the markdown library, in particular [this method](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_markdown/blob/master/lib/src/builder.dart#L125-L140):

```
  @override
  void visitText(md.Text text) {
    if (_blocks.last.tag == null) // Don't allow text directly under the root.
      return;

    _addParentInlineIfNeeded(_blocks.last.tag);

    final TextSpan span = _blocks.last.tag == 'pre'
      ? delegate.formatText(styleSheet, text.text)
      : new TextSpan(
          maxLines: 1,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          style: _inlines.last.style,
          text: text.text,
          recognizer: _linkHandlers.isNotEmpty ? _linkHandlers.last : null,
        );

    _inlines.last.children.add(new RichText(text: span));
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could create your own small HTML parser that composes a `TextSpan` (basically text with format), then render it using a `RichText` widget.

Comment: Thanks, I went with the solution suggested by Derek Lakin.